# Entityform view block not displaying on page

Tags: views, blocks

I can't seem to get Views-based blocks to show up on an Entityform page (Drupal 7). The View has a Contextual Filter of "Entityform Submission: Entityform submission ID". For the "When the filter value is not available" setting, I have "Provide default value: Content ID from URL" selected:

[image]

When I enter in an Entityform Submission ID in the Preview section, I get the results I'm after. However, when I place the Block on an Entityform page, it doesn't even show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I gave my brain some space from this problem and came up with a solution that works for me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by changing the "When the filter value is NOT available" setting to "Provide default value: Content ID from URL" and using the 2nd path component (which is the Entityform submission ID):

[image]

This works for me. But I can imagine a scenario where the ID is obscured from the URL and this wouldn't work.

Comment: I could be wrong but is it because block displays can’t read arguments in some cases? I feel like that was a thing in D7.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting. Maybe someone can confirm. And yes, I should specify that is Drupal 7.

Comment: If you do php filter and `return arg(2);` does it work?

Comment: @Kevin I'll try that… but, that's essentially the same thing as my answer which uses the 2nd path component, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain - does raw value from URL actually mean arg(2), or is it just whats in the second part of the URL (like the alias)?